# I am trying to get group name from the groupcollection based on the string match but i am unable to do

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, groups

I am trying to get group name from the groupcollection based on the string match but i am unable to do with the foreach statement  , please advice on my below script, i do not want to call onsuccess function or onerror functions so need to fix in the same code.

```
context = new SP.ClientContext('/mysite');
this.oWebsite = context.get_web();
context.load(this.oWebsite);
this.groupCollection = oWebsite.get_siteGroups();
context.load(this.groupCollection);

foreach ( Group group1 in groupCollection)
{
    if (group1.Name.ToLower().Contains(ClientCodeTrim.ToLower()))
    {
         PostMyGroup1 = group1.Name;
    }                               
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var siteUrl = '/mysite';
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
this.collGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
clientContext.load(collGroup);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var groupEnumerator = collGroup.getEnumerator();
    while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oGroup = groupEnumerator.get_current();

        if(oGroup.Name.ToLower().Contains(ClientCodeTrim.ToLower())) {
            PostMyGroup1 = oGroup.Name;
        }
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.i have tried with above code and it worked but my issue is i need to pass the matched result i.e. PostMYGroup1 immediately to next line of code..... currently all the script code is executing and finally its executing the onQuerysucceeded function so PostMYGroup1 value is getting null value.is there any way i can get the result immediately after executing executequeryAsync call

ex:

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

Var Group=PostMyGroup1(//get PostMyGroup1 value)
}

Comment: @Rags you should move all your other code inside the `onQuerySucceeded` function.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot go with that option to move the code.....is there any impact if i call any server side control or use callback function after executeQueryAsync method?

Comment: This is asynchronous call. So You need to find a way to serialize how the code gets executed. If you cant move the code, then atleast wrap the code into a function and invoke it from onQuerySucceeded

Comment: Thanks for your responses...slightly i modified the code as per my requirements and its worked....... thanks for assisting.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, you have just loaded the web and the sitegroups which do not actually have any information. Unless the request is sent to the server, you wont be able to get the groups information that you are iterating on. You will have to execute

```
context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess,onFailure)
```

in order to get the group collection information and then get the specific group. Any specific reason why you dont want to call onsuccess and failed functions ?